# Using AJAX to Access Files on my Server Leads to 404

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, image

I'm developing a website, and I'm trying to load images on the client side using AJAX. I know the relative path of the image on my server (relative to the file with the AJAX code). However, when I use that relative path to access the image, I get a 404 not found error.

My code to access the image is:

```
var image = "/images/1.jpg";

$.ajax({
 url: folder,
 type: 'HEAD',
 success: function(msg){
   console.log("Success: " + msg);
 },
 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
   alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
   alert(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
 }
```

I get a 404 error each time, although I'm sure my image is there.

Must I type the full URL of the image, ie, `localhost:3000/src/images/1.jpg`? In addition, why can't I access the image by typing its path into the browser bar? For example, typing `localhost:3000/src/images/1.jpg` yields nothing, although my image is under that path on the server. It seems to have moved to a /static/media folder, and can only be accessed using the url `http://localhost:3000/static/media/1.865aebec.jpg`.

Comment: Look at the network tab.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with AJAX; you need to configure your server to serve the paths you seem to expect it to.

Comment: Gotcha. How would I configure the server? Right now I'm just on localhost, but plan on moving to AWS when it's finished.

Comment: That completely depends on what server you're running.  Read the documentation.